# golang accepting input with spaces

Tags: input, go, space

I'm just starting with GO and I understand that SCANF uses spaces as a separator in GO.

```
fmt.Scanf("%s",&input)
```

I cant really find a way to accepts inputs that contain spaces as valid characters.

Comment: You've said you don't want to treat the space character as a delimiter.  What characters would count as delimiters?

Comment: When the user presses enter it signifies the end of input

Comment: this should be closed - no longer relevant with any later versions of go
it shows as the top answer in google and wastes everyone's time

Comment: @av192 I have edited my 2014 answer to include a better solution.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

My initial 2014 answer used [`fmt.Scanln`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Scanln) for this specific use case.
But `fmt.Scanln` also treats spaces as separators between inputs. That means it cannot directly read an entire line including spaces into a single string variable without additional handling.

---

A better option would be to use [`bufio.NewReader`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#NewReader) and its [`ReadString` method](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Reader.ReadString).
Unlike `fmt.Scanln`, `bufio.NewReader` with `ReadString` allows you to read an entire line of input, including spaces, into a single string until a newline character is encountered. That behavior is precisely what is needed to accept inputs like `"Hello there"` as a single string.

```
Using fmt.Scanln:        "Hello there" → "Hello"
Using bufio.NewReader:   "Hello there" → "Hello there"
```

Using `bufio.NewReader` to read a line of input, including spaces, until the user presses Enter (newline), would be:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter text: ")
    input, err := reader.ReadString('\n') // '\n' is the delimiter to stop reading
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // Trim the newline character from the input, if any
    input = strings.TrimSpace(input) 

    fmt.Println("You entered:", input)
}
```

You can test it on [playground `go.dev/play`](https://go.dev/play/p/hRvK_zGQb8U).

Remember, the `ReadString` method returns the delimiter as part of the input, so you may want to trim the input string to remove the newline character at the end.

Comment: The program runs by itself and does not wait for the user input when I use this function.

Comment: @av192 strange considering their respective implementations (https://github.com/golang/go/blob/439b32936367c3efd0dadab48dd51202e1a510f1/src/fmt/scan.go#L131-L148)

Comment: The referenced doc mentions Scan. From Scan: "... storing successive space-separated values into successive arguments." If you want to capture the whole input from stdin, I suggest bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin).

Comment: this does not the solve the problem of taking a string containing spaces as input. ie mystr = "Hello there"

Comment: @av192, note that if you pass the variable itself, instead of the address of the variable ( fmt.Scanln(var) instead of fmt.Scanln(&var) ), the issue of the program not waiting for user input crops up. Can someone throw light on the reason behind this behaviour?

Answer (score 41):

you can use bufio.Reader and os.Stdin:

```
import(
  "bufio"
  "os"
)

in := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

line, err := in.ReadString('\n')
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: I think the solution is to get input by the use of "bufio" library in golang. http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/

Comment: The read string will be `This is a string\n` whereas I wanted it to be `This is a string`.

Comment: Golang v1.2.0 works for me with another way:

```go
in := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
line, err = in.ReadString('\n')
```

Without ":=", only equals symbol

Comment: this is the wrong answer, it will output:

<nil>YOURIUNPUT\n

Comment: this is wrong, it returns

<nil>YOURINPUT\n

Answer (score 37):

Similar to @chlin's answer, use bufio to capture whole lines.

The fmt Scan methods store each space separated value into a successive arguments. Three arguments on stdin would require something like:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var day, year int
    var month string
    fmt.Scanf("%d %s %d", &day, &month, &year)
    fmt.Printf("captured: %d %s %d\n", day, month, year)
}
```

If you don't know the full format of what you will be reading and just want the line, use bufio:

```
package main

import (
  "bufio"
  "os"
  "fmt"
)

func main(){
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    scanner.Scan() // use `for scanner.Scan()` to keep reading
    line := scanner.Text()
    fmt.Println("captured:",line)
}
```

Comment: What would you adapt here to make it take `n` inputs?

Answer (score 1):

When using ReadString('\n'), it reads until and including the newline character. If you want to remove this trailing newline from the input string, you can use the strings.TrimSpace function.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Please enter a string: ")
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    text = strings.TrimSpace(text)  // Remove any surrounding whitespace including the newline.
    fmt.Printf("You entered: %s", text)
}
```